# Remove solution from TFS?

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2012, tfs, windows-explorer, team-explorer

I've removed my project from source control and the TFS symbols don't appear in VS anymore. However, in Windows Explorer there are still signs of TFS. I want to completely un-recognize this project for TFS.

I already deleted the team and the project in the TFS management portal but those symbols (see bellow) still appear.

Here's is what it looks in Win Explorer like:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the local workspace cache for that machine. You can reset the cache with the following command (this might not be necessary):

```
tf workspaces /remove:*
```

And then repopulate it with:

```
tf workspaces /s:http://tfsservername:8080/tfs/Collection
```

Further info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/09/12/path-is-already-mapped-in-workspace.aspx

And documentation for the workspaces command: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54dkh0y3.aspx

Comment: You have access to the tf.exe command automatically if you use the 'Visual Studio Command Prompt' shortcut which is in you start menu under 'Visual Studio Tools'

Comment: Didn't work. as soon as I set back the TFS the symbols come back for this project eventho the team's been entirely removed from TFS.

Comment: I don't know what 'TFS management portal' is, but in case you've deleted the items elsewhere than your local workspace you probably need to get latest.

Comment: I thought workspace is a server thing. TFS mgmt portal refers to the website that manages my TFS projects i.e. `https://mytfs.visualstudio.com`.

Comment: I have not worked with the online TFS Services, so I do not know how the "management portal" you mention works. I suggest you try to right click the workspace folder which contains the project you've removed in explorer, and choose Get Latest. This should synchronize your local workspace with what is present on the server.

Comment: But I don't want to sync it, I want to make it work as a simple folder just as the Program Files folder or any other folder in the system.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think you can achieve that with TFS. That is simply not the way TFS workspaces function.